# What is this syntax in GSP pages?

Tags: grails, gsp

```
    {{#isFinal type}}
            <div class="summary" section='summary'>
                {{#logics data.remaining}}
                <div id="remaining" field='remaining' class="notifybox"><div class="warnicon"> {{remainingMessage}} </div></div>
                {{else}}
                <div id="remaining" field='remaining' class="notifybox"><div class="warnicon"> {{remainingMessage}} </div></div>
                {{/logics}}
...
...
..
```

What is the double quotes about? Is ({{ ....}}) Grails syntax?

Comment: Out of context that's difficult to say. I would recommend including the entire GSP not just the fragment. It could be a client-side javascript template of some sort, or some other view processor on the server-side. However, it's not standard GSP syntax.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is definitely not syntax for Grails but for any Javascript template like Handlebars http://handlebarsjs.com/